# c# NHibernate doesn't wrap entity with proxy

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GroupPhrases](
    [GroupId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PhraseId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Quality] [float] NOT NULL,
    [VerdictsCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IntersectionPercentage] [float] NULL,
    [VerdictIds] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [RelevanceResult] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_GroupPhrases] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GroupId] ASC,
    [PhraseId] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And here is the entity of the table:

```
public class GroupPhraseEntity
{
    public virtual int GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual PhraseEntity Phrase { get; set; }
    public virtual double Quality { get; set; }
    public virtual int VerdictsCount { get; set; }
    public virtual double? IntersectionPercentage { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] VerdictIds { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] RelevanceResult { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var castObj = obj as GroupPhraseEntity;
        if (castObj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return (GroupId == castObj.GroupId) && (Phrase.Id == castObj.Phrase.Id);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And here is the mapping:

```
public class GroupPhraseEntityMap : ClassMapping<GroupPhraseEntity>
{
    public GroupPhraseEntityMap()
    {
        Table("GroupPhrases");

        ComposedId(map =>
        {
            map.Property(x => x.GroupId);
            map.ManyToOne(x => x.Phrase, m =>
            {
                m.Column("PhraseId");
            });
        });
        Property(x => x.Quality);
        Property(x => x.IntersectionPercentage);
        Property(x => x.VerdictsCount);
        Property(x => x.VerdictIds, m =>
        {
            m.Column("VerdictIds");
            m.Type(NHibernateUtil.BinaryBlob);
            m.Length(Int32.MaxValue);
            m.Lazy(true);
        });
        Property(x => x.RelevanceResult, m =>
        {
            m.Column("RelevanceResult");
            m.Type(NHibernateUtil.BinaryBlob);
            m.Length(Int32.MaxValue);
            m.Lazy(true);
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the method that should return RelevanceResult field value:

```
    public RelevanceResult GetGroupRelevanceResult(int groupId, int phraseId)
    {
        using (var session = _sessionManager.GetSession())
        {
            var groupPhrase = session.Query<GroupPhraseEntity>().FirstOrDefault(x => (x.GroupId == groupId) && (x.Phrase.Id == phraseId));
            if (groupPhrase == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return Deserialize<RelevanceResult>(groupPhrase.RelevanceResult);
        }
    }
```

But the method fails me, since the RelevanceResult property is not loading!!! I see that the query returns me not wrapped with proxy object and the field RelevanceResult stays null.
Any ideas why is that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you get null or an exception? Did you had a look on the generated sql?

Comment: I get null, and as result the exception in Deserialize method

Comment: Did you took a look on the generated sql? You can use [NhProfiler](https://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof) for this.

Comment: It doesn't load the lazy fields in sql. And that's Ok. What is not good, that it doesn't load the lazy field value when I trying to get it in the code... And IMHO the reason for that - the loaded entity is not wrapped by NHibernate proxy. So sql is not relevant here, but here it is:  SELECT groupphras0_.GroupId as Groupi1_5_0_, groupphras0_.PhraseId as Prasei2_5_0_, groupphras0_.Quality as Qualit3_5_0_, 
groupphras0_.VerdictsCount as Verdic4_5_0_, groupphras0_.IntersectionPercentage as Inters5_5_0_ 
FROM GroupPhrases groupphras0_ 
WHERE groupphras0_.GroupId=@p0 and groupphras0_.PhraseId=@p1

Comment: Try to fetch the data: `session.Query<GroupPhraseEntity>().Fetch(x => x.RelevanceResult).FirstOrDefault(x => (x.GroupId == groupId) && (x.Phrase.Id == phraseId))` You should already did that, because its lazy and you only want `RelevanceResult`. Maybe that resolves your issue.

Comment: I have found that the problem is in using ComposedId in mapping. I have added field Id to the table and removed ComposedId. It fixed the issue. But it looks like a bug in NHibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the problem is in using ComposedId in mapping. I have added field Id to the table and removed ComposedId. It fixed the issue. But it looks like a bug in NHibernate

Answer (score 0):

`RelevanceRankingResult` is a lazy property. If `_sessionManager.GetSession()` returns an `IStatelessSession`, you need to explicitly `Select()` it (and all the other columns you want to output in `Deserialize()`

Comment: No, _sessionManager.GetSession() returns ISession. So it should work... But doesn't...